# How to switch off subpixel antialiasing in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, font

Is there a way to permanently switch off subpixel antialiasing in Safari OSX 10.8?

Comment: Have you poked at [the `AppleFontSmoothing` default that can be written from a command line?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32592/applefontsmoothing-has-no-effect-on-my-viewsonic-vx2450)

Answer (score 3):

Save this with a .css extension somewhere and select it as the custom stylesheet in Preferences > Advanced:

```
html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

`defaults write com.apple.Safari AppleFontSmoothing -int 0` would also disable subpixel rendering in the UI.